# Dropbox synching (rename)

Tags: php, dropbox, rename

I am trying to keep my files updated via a Dropbox synchronisation. The setup:

1. I am using [Dropbox webhooks](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/webhooks/docs) to get notified of changes in the box
2. I ask the Dropbox server for a [/delta](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta)
3. I analyze the delta array

The array consists of multiple entries, however (for me), a question remains: how do I determine if a file has simply been renamed instead of added to the box? I want to process the files further but want to avoid double entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, Dropbox itself can't distinguish between a rename and a delete+add, so it can't tell you what happened with that precision. You'll need to come up with your own definition for what a rename means to you (e.g. a delete and add close together in time where the file contents are the same) and then use that definition.

Using a hash of the file contents is sufficient for a lot of apps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what about big file sizes (1gb+) ? We are dealing with a lot of video files. So I would need to download the new file, calculate a hash (Dropbox does not provide one, am I right?) and then decide if it's new or renamed. Would that be the correct approach?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately Dropbox doesn't provide a content hash, so you'd have to download the file. Some people use file size as an approximation (a delete and an add close together in time with the same file size counts as a rename).